# Setup Solr for ezPublish

Tags: solr, ezpublish

I am using eZPublis(4.6.0). I have set solr folder folder in my xampp folder and activated the eZFind extension in \settings\override\site.ini.append.php.

My solr is runing on port 8080 ("http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/"). when I run "http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/", it loads fine.

However, when I try to run command : php extension/ezfind/bin/php/updatesearchindexsolr.php -s
it shows following error “Please, ensure the server is started and the configuration of eZ Find is correct”. I am following http://harmssite.com/post/86#comment-113.

Can anyone suggest what wrong I may be doing or any other solution?

Comment: Do you use the solr instance which is bundled with ezfind or a custom installation ? Please note that solr normally listen on port 8983 (at least the ezfind one).

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that solr is running then you might need to edit solr.ini (or one of its overrides) and use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. I've faced this issue sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

The default Solr port is `8983`, so eZ Find out of the box is set up to look at that port. If you are sure that Solr is up and running on port `8080` then look in your `solr.ini` to verify you have eZ Find pointed at the right Solr port.